# Socket in reactjs is not connected

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I want to use sockets in my application. For this i used nest js:

```js
import {
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import {
  Socket
} from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(81, {
  transports: ['websocket']
})
export class EventsGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {

  afterInit(server: any): any {
    console.log('initi', server.nsps.connected);
  }

  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    console.log('online connect', client.id);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('events')

  handleEvent(client: Socket, data: string) {
    console.log(data, 'socket');

    return {
      event: 'test',
      data: 'data'
    };
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: any): any {
    console.log('disc');
  }
}
```

UI in react js

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:81/test";
// const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:3000/test";

let socket: any;

function App() {
    useEffect(()=> {
        socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, {transports: ['websocket']});
        console.log(socket.connected, 'conneted or not') // return false 
    })




    function sendEmail(e: any) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        socket.emit('events', {name: 'Nest'});
       
        socket.on('test', (res: any) => {
            console.log(res); // should log 'hello'
        });
        console.log('send', socket);
    }


    return (
        <div className="App">
           ...
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Every time checking `console.log(socket.connected, 'conneted or not')`, i get `false`, even on nest js server i can see if the client access the socket or leave the page, but this:

```js
 @SubscribeMessage('events')

  handleEvent(client: Socket, data: string) {
    console.log(data, 'socket');

    return {
      event: 'test',
      data: 'data'
    };
 }
```

...doe not work and i can't see when i send socket from UI or the sockets that are sent from the server. What could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: @ZeroCho, change the version of sockets on UI to: `"socket.io-client": "^2.3.1"`. If it works, let me know please.

Comment: Downgrading from 3.1.0 to 2.4.0 works. Thank you. I've read that nest.js is not compatible with socket.io@3, so I installed @2 on the server but forgot to install @2 on the client.

Comment: Hey guys what version are you using in Nest?